# How to make google fonts visible for mobile?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, google-fonts

I am developing a portfolio and I used google fonts in it. But I am unable to display it on the mobile. Please find the portfolio [here](https://mani5871.github.io/)
You can find the head tag below

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Courgette&family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet
```

Comment: Plz don't provide external links to sites, it might be some `@media` query and u have used `.d-none {
    display: none!important;
}` for smaller screens on text

Answer (score 0):

You have `.d-none` set to `display: none !important;` on some media queries which is why the text disappears on smaller screens

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the link tag does not work on mobile browser . It's better to use CSS import :

```
   <style>

      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
      family=Courgette&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0
     ,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500&
      display=swap');
    
   </style>
```